# Detener un loop en base a una respuesta de AJAX en Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente código:
La idea del $.getJSON es chequear el stock de todos los ID de productos que son obtenidos con e = JSON.parse(ui.item.productos).  Lo que no logro hacer es que, si detecta que alguno de los productos tiene stock 0 o menor a la cantidad estipulada, no ejecute la función agregarProducto(); o o directamente frene el bucle $.each. Probé añadiendo una variable que se setee como true si detecta que uno de los productos no tiene stock, pero igual se ejecuta la función con los productos que sí tienen stock, lo cual la idea es que si alguno tiene un faltante, no se ejecute en ningún producto.

```
 var e = JSON.parse(ui.item.productos),
     r = '',
     i = 0,
     s = false;
     
$(e).each(function(a){
    ++i;
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'promociones/checkStock', 'id=' + e[a]['id'], function(res){
        r = res;
        if(res['stock'] == 0 || res['stock'] < e[a]['cantidad']) {
            s = true; 
            alertaPersonalizada('warning', 'STOCK NO DISPONIBLE DEL PRODUCTO ' + res['nombre']);
            return;
        }
        //agregarProducto(e[a]['id'], e[a]['cantidad'], res['stock'], e[a]['nombre']);
    });
    if(!s) agregarProducto(e[i]['id'], e[i]['cantidad'], r['stock'], e[i]['nombre']);
});
```

Comment: Inserta el codigo completo, [edit] tu pregunta, para que te puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` es una función asíncrona.

Suponga que tiene 20 productos en `e`. El bucle `.each()` comienza su trabajo y muy rápidamente envía las 20 solicitudes para cada uno de los productos. -- ¡Aún no se obtienen las respuestas!

Inmediatamente, la condición `if(!s)` se ejecuta 20 veces ANTES de obtener las respuestas...
`s` siempre es `false`.
`r` siempre es `''`.

Por tanto, es preferible utilizar el elemento proporcionado por el bucle `.each()` (segundo argumento). Para asegurarse de que este elemento sea el correcto cuando se reciba la respuesta, debe asignarse a una variable limitada al alcance ("scope" en inglès) de esta iteración usando `const`.

Finalmente, la llamada a la función `aggregarProducto` debe hacerse en la función callback de `$.getJSON()` que se ejecuta cuando se obtiene la respuesta.

**PD**: No sé qué es `ui.item.productos`... Pero asumo que el bucle `.each()` funciona bien.

```
const e = JSON.parse(ui.item.productos)
     
$(e).each(function(indice, elemento){
  
    // Use una variable constante aquí
    const estaElemento = elemento
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'promociones/checkStock', 'id=' + estaElemento.id, function(res){

        if(res.stock == 0 || res.stock < estaElemento.cantidad) { 
            alertaPersonalizada('warning', 'STOCK NO DISPONIBLE DEL PRODUCTO ' + res.nombre);
            return;
        }
        agregarProducto(estaElemento.id, estaElemento.cantidad, res.stock, estaElemento.nombre);
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Para agregar los productos solo si están todos en stock, debe usar una variable "flag" y un segundo ciclo.

ver `todoLasProductosDisponible`

```
const e = JSON.parse(ui.item.productos)

const todoLasProductosDisponible = true
let productos = []
     
$(e).each(function(indice, elemento){
  
    // Use una variable constante aquí
    const estaElemento = elemento
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'promociones/checkStock', 'id=' + estaElemento.id, function(res){

        if(res.stock == 0 || res.stock < estaElemento.cantidad) { 
            alertaPersonalizada('warning', 'STOCK NO DISPONIBLE DEL PRODUCTO ' + res.nombre);
            todoLasProductosDisponible = false
            return;
        }
        productos.push({
          id: estaElemento.id,
          cantidad: estaElemento.cantidad,
          stock: res.stock,
          nombre: estaElemento.nombre
        })
    });
});

if(todoLasProductosDisponible) {
  productos.forEach((producto) => {
    agregarProducto(producto.id, producto.cantidad, producto.stock, producto.nombre);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente código, quedó mucho más ordenado! El problema es que sigue estando la misma cuestión, por más que no haya stock disponible de algún producto x y aparezca el mensaje de stock no disponible, si alguno de los otros productos de la promoción si tiene stock, agregarProducto() se ejecuta igual. La idea es que dicha función no se ejecute si en algún momento de la iteración se cumple el siguiente condicional if(res.stock == 0 || res.stock < estaElemento.cantidad)

Comment: Vale lo entiendo. Edité mi respuesta.